Could not build wheels for tokenizers
This is my first ever question on stack overflow. Nice to meet yall.:)
I am trying to follow the "Requirements and Installation" steps given in the readme of the Video-LLaVA Repo https://github.com/PKU-YuanGroup/Video-LLaVA.
First of all I experienced a lot of dependency issues and I am constantly changing the versions specified in the pyproject.toml. The main issues are about the versions of torch and torchvision.
Currently my dependencies look like this:
dependencies = [
    "torch==2.2.1", "torchvision==0.17.1",
    "transformers==4.31.0", "tokenizers>=0.12.1,<0.14", "sentencepiece==0.2.0", "shortuuid",
    "accelerate==0.21.0", "peft==0.4.0", "bitsandbytes==0.41.0",
    "pydantic<2,>=1", "markdown2[all]", "numpy", "scikit-learn==1.2.2",
    "requests", "httpx==0.24.0", "uvicorn", "fastapi",
    "einops==0.6.1", "einops-exts==0.0.4", "timm==0.6.13",
    "tensorboardX==2.6.2.2", "gradio==3.37.0", "gradio_client==0.7.0"
]

Now I am getting the error:
Successfully built videollava
Failed to build tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Some sources say its because of a missing rust installation but I did already install it.
Does anybody have any clue or experience with this? I am very thankful for any help!
